# Flowchart automation

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm wondering if somebody could help, find the best way how to create a flowchart organization structure from Data on an SQL server?

- It needs to be fully automated.
- Easy to reed

Thank you for your answers.

[The example of the flow chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THT1v.png)

Comment: You could use hierarchyid on sql server , or use an appropriate Graph or Document database. Doing this relationally in vanilla SQL (although common) is a pain (which is why they invented hierarchyid)

Comment: "It needs to be fully automated" - can you elaborate on what that means to you? A table structure in and of itself doesn't *do* anything so "automation" doesn't make sense in that context. What operations do you need to run against this table?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you need to create hierarchical structure. To resolve this task you may create table like:

```
CREATE TABLE Organization(
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Name] [varchar](256) NOT NULL,
[ParentId] [int] NOT NULL REFERENCES Organization(Id))
```

Here `Id` is primary key. `ParentId` is `Id` of parent node. For root node `ParentId = 0`.

But Microsoft recommends to use `hierarchyId` for hierarchical structure. So table should be like

```
CREATE TABLE Organization(
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Name] [varchar](256) NOT NULL,
[TreeAddress] [hierarchyid] NOT NULL,
[Level] AS [TreeAddress].GetLevel()
)
```

More details about `hierarchyid`  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/tutorial-using-the-hierarchyid-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: For what it's worth, I like to use both a ParentID and a hierarchyid column. I find that it's easy to get corruption in the hierarchyid (not because of MS's implementation but rather a bug in the application's update logic) and having a way to re-generate it by traversing ParentIDs back to the root is useful. YMMV.